# Generic object returned instead of class entity in hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate

I am running a hibernate query which is returning an Object instead of the correct entity object.  The statement is as follows:

```
public List getPriorBids(String rfpCD, String carrierCode) {
    String sqlString =  " SELECT inland_cd, " +
                                "rfp_cd, " +
                                "carrier_cd, " +
                                "port_cd, " +
                                "max(iteration_nb) as iteration_nb " +
                        " FROM care.inland_bid " +
                        " WHERE rfp_cd = :rfpCode " +
                        "   AND carrier_cd = :carrierCode " +
                        " GROUP BY inland_cd, rfp_cd, carrier_cd, port_cd " +
                        " ORDER BY inland_cd, carrier_cd"; 
    SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sqlString);
    sqlQuery.setString("carrierCode",carrierCode);
    sqlQuery.setString("rfpCode", rfpCD);
    sqlQuery.addEntity(Bid.class);
    List bids = sqlQuery.list();
    return bids;
   }
```

Clearly I am trying to store it as a Bid object.  I have another object as well which I should be storing it as but I get an error that the column name cannot be found, despite double and triple checking column names to make sure they match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Query.list()` returns a raw `List` object](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29), not a generic `List`.

You should just be able to cast it to `List<Bid>`, and ignore the unsafe cast warning.

I think you are confusing a method which returns a raw `List` with the actual run-time type of the List elements being `Object`. Just because the compile-time signature of `List.get(i)` returns an `Object` does not mean that the actual type of the element returned is `Object` at run-time.

Comment: I thought addEntity(class) changed the return type of the object to the specified class type if it was able to fit.  I have it returning a list of objects (took out the addEntity) but casting them into List<Bid> later doesn't appear to change the object (at least as far as the debugger shows).

Answer (score 1):

If using JPA 2, you can create a `TypedQuery` which supports generics